# Connecting Keycloak with Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, docker, keycloak, quarkus

I am trying to connect Keycloak (20.0.3) with Postgres database using Docker. These are the steps that I've taken to configure it:

```
1. docker network create keycloak-network
2. docker run --name postgresP -p 5432:5432 -d --net keycloak-network -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin -e POSTGRES_USER=admin -e POSTGRES_DB=pdb -d postgres:latest
3. docker run -p 9090:9090 --name keycloakP --net keycloak-network -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin -e KC_DB=postgres -e KC_DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/pdb -e KC_DB_USERNAME=admin -e KC_DB_PASSWORD=admin quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest start-dev
```

But I am getting the following error. I tried to troubleshoot but unfortunately the documentation for Keycloak is not that great. Any leads will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
2023-02-10 11:08:36,986 DEBUG [io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader] (main) Adding elements io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.PathTreeClassPathElement[io.quarkus:quarkus-devservices-common / runtime=false resources=null] to QuarkusClassLoader Augmentation Class Loader: PROD

2023-02-10 11:08:36,987 DEBUG [io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader] (main) Adding elements io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.PathTreeClassPathElement[io.quarkiverse.vault:quarkus-vault-deployment / runtime=false resources=null] to QuarkusClassLoader Augmentation Class Loader: PROD

2023-02-10 11:08:36,987 DEBUG [io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader] (main) Adding elements io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.PathTreeClassPathElement[org.keycloak:keycloak-quarkus-server-deployment / runtime=false resources=null] to QuarkusClassLoader Augmentation Class Loader: PROD

2023-02-10 11:08:39,257 DEBUG [io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader] (main) Adding elements io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.PathTreeClassPathElement[/ runtime=true resources=null] to QuarkusClassLoader Deployment Class Loader: PROD

2023-02-10 11:08:39,290 DEBUG [io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor] (main) Beginning Quarkus augmentation

2023-02-10 11:08:40,193 TRACE [io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader] (main) Class quarkus.properties not found in parent first load from java.net.URLClassLoader@192c3f1e

2023-02-10 11:08:40,194 TRACE [io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader] (main) Class quarkus.properties not found in parent first load from java.net.URLClassLoader@192c3f1e

ERROR: Failed to run 'build' command.
ERROR: No value present
```

What I am trying to achieve is use custom DB for Keycloak instead of H2 and later on, create persistent users/configs via same.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You `KC_DB_URL` setting is incorrect; Postgres is not running on `localhost` (which would mean, "in the keycloak container"); it's running in your `postgresP` container, so you need to use that contianer name as the hostname:

```
KC_DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgresP:5432/pdb
```

This isn't going to result in a working configuration because when you're starting the Keycloak container you're setting `-p 9090:9090`, but Keycloak is listening on port 8080 inside the container, so you would need `-p 9090:8080`.

You don't need to publish ports (`-p 5432:5432`) on the postgres container in order to access it from the keycloak container; the port publishing is only necessary if you want to access the database from your host or elsewhere on the network.

---

A couple of comments unrelated to the problem:

1. Using `postgres:latest` as your image is going to cause problems at some point when `:latest` unexpectedly gets you a new major version of Postgres; use an explicit version instead (e.g. `postgres:15`).

   The same holds true for most images -- it's almost always a good idea to pin to a specific version (or at least a specific major version).
2. Do yourself a favor and use [`docker compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) instead of manually running a bunch of `docker run` commands. Your current configuration could be represented by the following `docker-compose.yaml`:

   ```
   services:
     postgres:
       image: postgres:15
       environment:
         POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin
         POSTGRES_USER: admin
         POSTGRES_DB: pdb
     keycloak:
       image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:20.0
       environment:
         KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
         KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
         KC_DB: postgres
         KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres/pdb
         KC_DB_USERNAME: admin
         KC_DB_PASSWORD: admin
       ports:
         - 9090:8080
       command:
         - start-dev
   ```

   Put the above in `docker-compose.yaml` and then run `docker compose up`.

   You'll note that I am *not* publishing postgres ports in this example, in line with my earlier comment.
3. Regardless of whether you're using `docker compose` or just multiple `docker run` command lines, you probably want to use a Docker volume for your postgres data so that you don't lose everything when you restart the container.

   I haven't configured that in my example, but you'll find appropriate examples in the official docs and all over the place on this website.